# How to Implement Google Authentication Using Expo.AppAuth in a Bare React Native Application?

Tags: react-native, expo, appauth

I am trying to implement Google authentication using Expo.AppAuth in my react native bare application (not managed by Expo). 

I am using the expo-app-auth package. 

I created a Client ID on Google Developer Console using the following bundle ID "org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp"


Here is my code:

```
import * as AppAuth from 'expo-app-auth';
AppAuth.authAsync({
    issuer: 'https://accounts.google.com',
    clientId: '<My_Client_ID>',
    scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
});
```

The above code redirects to Safari and gives the following error:

```
Safari cannot open the page because it could not establish a secure connection to the server.
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Is iOSDevice a real device, not an emulator?

Comment: It is an emulator, not a real device. In fact, now that you mentioned it, I am going to check on a real device.